# Detect current city without network connection

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to retrieve the current city name by using `reverseGeocodeLocation` but the problem is that it needs a network connection.

The question I have is there any alternative method to retrieve the current city name without network connection?

Comment: You can get a close approximation from the sim data. One sec... Ah, my mistake. You can get the country but not the city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location manager ('CLLocationManager') returns an array of CLLocation objects. A CLLocation object contains latitude and longitude information.

What you can do is:

1. Find a database that includes geolocation information, specifically mappings of coordinates to city names.
2. Check if the coordinates returned from the location manager fall within a certain threshold of any of the cities in the database.

Comment: "Without network connection". If you can do what you describe then you can just ask Apple through CoreLocation what the current city is.

Comment: What I proposed does NOT need a network connection. CLLocationManager works without an internet connection. Try it yourself.

Comment: yeah I know it does. I didn't realise you meant a database of cities that you bundle into the device offline.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. No worries :)

Answer (score 1):

You may collect a rough shape(rectangle, circle) with co-ordinates of the cities you want; then compare with your current location data to get the city or area as you stored it locally. Though it is no t exact, it is close enough to work with.